# Problems positioning element based on browser width

Tags: javascript, css-position

I have a fixed position div that I want to have position left: 0 when the browser window is smaller than 1200px, but no left positioning when larger than 1200px.  I'm using this code

```
var $window = $(window);
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    document.write(windowsize);
    if (windowsize < 1200) {
        document.getElementById("DBCIbox").style.left = "0";
    } else {50
        document.getElementById("DBCIbox").style.left = "500px";
    }
}
checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

but it doesnt seem to be doing anything.  I'm setting the left=500px as simply a test to get the javascript working, then I'll worry about where I want to position it.

I've done some googleing and from what I can tell this should work, what am I missing?

If theres a way to clear the left positioning I'd like to know that as well.

Comment: What is this "    } else {50" ?

Comment: "} else {50" is a copy-paste error.  That "50" is not in my code, apparently I need to proofread my posts better.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $window = $(window);
```

That line is cacheing that instance of window. You need to re-evaluate `$(window)` everytime you call this code to get updated width and height values

Updated code below

```
function checkWidth() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    document.write(windowsize);
    if (windowsize < 1200) {
        document.getElementById("DBCIbox").style.left = "0";
    } else {50
        document.getElementById("DBCIbox").style.left = "500px";
    }
}

checkWidth();

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Comment: Okay, I made that change, however the code is still not working.  This code doesn't even work on the initial page load, my browser window is 1900px which obviously is larger than the specified 1200 but the div still appears at left: 0.

Comment: Finally figured this one out.  For some reason I couldn't change the left property, but I could change the margin-left property.  I answered my own question so that I could post updated code, but much of the code was yours and you deserve the credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Jnatalzia had it right, I needed to make a few tweaks, and the comments wouldn't let me post the code, but credit goes to @Jnatalzia for the answer.

```
   function checkWidth() {
        var $window = $(window);
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        var position;       
        if (windowsize < 1390) {
            document.getElementById("DBCIbox").style.marginLeft = 0 + "px";
        } else if (windowsize >= 1390) {
            position = windowsize - 1060;
        position = position / 2;
        position = position - 175;
            document.getElementById("DBCIbox").style.marginLeft = position + "px";
        }
    }

    $("document").ready(function(){

       $(window).load(function(){
          checkWidth();
       });

       $(window).resize(function(){
          checkWidth();
       });

    });
```